# Is this a valid network diagram?

Tags: routing, vlan, subnet, dhcp, topology

I'm studing how to create a network diagram to this problem

The problem is: 7 condominiums with 7 floors each one, each floor has 4 apartments

The project is needed to use VLANs, Routers, DHCP, DNS's, Firewall and Proxy

[image: Diagram]

Can I do the connection to the apartments direct of the Firewall like I did?

Is right the IPs of the appartments?

Did I have represented right the VLAN's?

Though incomplete, I need to know if until here the diagram is right, or if there's errors

Thank you a lot for any suggestions and corrections

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Ron Trunk](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2142/ron-trunk) and [YLearn](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/33/ylearn) for contributing, I wish upvote but I'm not ranked

I've made some changes, if someone can take a look, find errors or made any other suggetions I will be greatful :)

[image: Diagram II]

Comment: 1. You don't show the proxy.  2. Firewalls do not have that many interfaces.  You will need another switch to connect all the apartments. 3. You should also include port names on the devices.   4. Most importantly, consider who will be using the diagram, and include the information most helpful to them.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't keep the IP scheme simpler? Maybe something along the lines of 10.[Bldg#].[Floor#Apt#].0/24. Building 3, second apartment on the sixth floor would then be 10.3.62.0/24 instead of 10.10.78.0/24. Could still have the VLAN follow the second and third octet (so 362 in my example). Would save a lot of hassle in troubleshooting later; let's you figure it out on the spot without having to check [possibly missing/outdated] documentation. May not work in larger buildings, but in the scenario you describe it would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you're asking us to critique the drawing or your network design.  The design seems OK from a superficial point of view, but since you have included hardly any requirements, it's hard to say whether everything will work as desired.

I do notice that the servers are on the same subnet as the external firewall interface. I don't think that is what you want, unless you have some magical L2/L3 firewall.  Also the firewall IP and GW are the same.

You don't show the IP addresses of the firewall links.  If the access points are bridging, then you need to decide if the firewall interfaces are all on the same subnet or not.  If the access points are L3, then you need to show the IP addresses of the access points.  In the latter case, you probably don't need VLANs at all.

The drawing itself is missing things that would help someone who had to troubleshoot this network:

- Show the switch interfaces that your routers are connected to.  That
  will help someone isolate problems more quickly.
- Show interfaces on the firewall, so one knows what is connected
  where.

Comment: @DigaoParceiro If this answer is helpful, please consider accepting the answer, so it doesn't keep popping up on this list.